# Set text in a Text view

Tags: java, android, textview

I have this adapter which the text view instantiate. 
But i want to change the text in the fragment.
what should i do?

Adapter which i used holder:

```
 holder.btnRedeem = vi.findViewById(R.id.btnRedeem);
            vi.setTag(holder);
```

Fragment:

```
(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnRedeem)).setText("redeem");
```

Answer (score 0):

create an interface in your adapter and implement it in your fragment.

check my answer for this question:

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521136](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521136/recyclerview-item-onclick-to-open-a-fragment-from-main-activity-fragment/58523133#58523133)
>
> check adapter and fragment (not activity)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle in adapter

```
holder.btnRedeem.setText("redeem")
```

If you want to handle in Fragment, you need to get the position of your item & apply text to the TextView.